# JQuery исчезновение кнопки "вверх"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Я использую фреймворк Bootstrap 4, приделав к [[cайту](http://test.expertpc.by)](http://test.expertpc.by/) кнопку `.arrow-top` используя jquery код для её функционала.

Интересует вопрос, как при открытии модального окна её спрятать, а при закрытии таки снова появилась от той позиции которая указана в коде:

```js
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
  if ($('.modal:visible').length) {
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
  }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.arrow-top').hide(); // Прячем кнопку
    
    $(function() {
    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {  // Где она должна появиться
      
    $('.arrow-top').fadeIn(); // Появление кнопки
      
    } else {
      
    $('.arrow-top').fadeOut(); // Исчезновение
      
    }
      
    });
      
    $('.arrow-top').click(function() {
      
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},800); // Скорость анимации
      return false;
    });

    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('modal-open').length) {
        $('.arrow-top').hide();
    }
});
```

```css
.arrow-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 125px;
  z-index: 9999;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  animation: fadeInRight 1s 1 cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>


<p>Много текста</p>
<p>Много текста</p>



<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#diagnostics">Подробнее</button>


<p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p>



<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="diagnostics">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center;">Диагностика ноутбука / компьютера</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="button-close">
          <div class="button-center">
            <p>- Диагностика может быть как у вас
              <strong>на дому</strong> так и в сервисном центре.</p>
            <p>После диагностики мастер всегда расскажет вам:</p>
            <p><b>1</b>. О текущей неисправности (поломке)
              <br> <b>2</b>. О ценах на
              <b>услуги</b> и
              <b>комплектующие</b>;
              <br> Предлагает все возможные решения устранения поломки и примерное время восстановления работоспособности.
              <br> <b>3</b>. О других возможных
              <b>аппаратных</b> или
              <b>программных сбоях.</b>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align:center;">Диагностика при заказе ремонта
              <b>бесплатная.</b>
              <p style="text-align:center;">
                <small>Без услуг ремонта - 20 РУБ.</small>
              </p>
              <div class="button-center" align="center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#call">Заказать звонок</button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Modal -->


<div class="arrow-top">
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i>
</div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Как например стилями скрывать:

```js
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
  if ($('.modal:visible').length) {
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
  }
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('.arrow-top').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.arrow-top').fadeOut();
  }
});


$('.arrow-top').click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.arrow-top {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 125px;
  z-index: 1009;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  animation: fadeInRight 1s 1 cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; 
  
  
  /* Стили для наглядности */
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
}

/* Скрываем, когда открыто модальное окно */
.modal-open .arrow-top {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

  
  
  
  
<p>Много текста</p>
<p>Много текста</p>
<p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p>



<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#diagnostics">Подробнее</button>


<p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p><p>Много текста</p>



<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="diagnostics">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center;">Диагностика ноутбука / компьютера</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="button-close">
          <div class="button-center">
            <p>- Диагностика может быть как у вас
              <strong>на дому</strong> так и в сервисном центре.</p>
            <p>После диагностики мастер всегда расскажет вам:</p>
            <p><b>1</b>. О текущей неисправности (поломке)
              <br> <b>2</b>. О ценах на
              <b>услуги</b> и
              <b>комплектующие</b>;
              <br> Предлагает все возможные решения устранения поломки и примерное время восстановления работоспособности.
              <br> <b>3</b>. О других возможных
              <b>аппаратных</b> или
              <b>программных сбоях.</b>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align:center;">Диагностика при заказе ремонта
              <b>бесплатная.</b>
              <p style="text-align:center;">
                <small>Без услуг ремонта - 20 РУБ.</small>
              </p>
              <div class="button-center" align="center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#call">Заказать звонок</button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Modal -->


<div class="arrow-top">
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i>
</div>
```